# Is it possible to use [HttpPost] attribute on JsonResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, http, post

I use MVC 3 in Asp.net I need to send HTTP POST date to a Control.
The control should send back some JSON as response.
At the moment I'm using this code, but I'm not able to get the Form field in the `collection` .

Any idea what is wrong?

```
         [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult LogOn(FormCollection collection, string returnUrl)
            {
    ...
return this.Json(new { success = "true", msg = messages[0] });
    }
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Test LogOn</h1>
    <form action="/Controller/LogOn" method="post">
    UserName:
    <input type="text" name="UserName"><br>
    Password:
    <input type="text" name="Password"><br>
    RememberMe:
    <input type="hidden" name="RememberMe" value="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your current code for sending the data to the server? JsonResult only tells how the data is going to be sent from the server to the client.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I made an edit to my question. Let me know thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If there was problem with `HttpPostAttribute`, you would not have been able to get inside `LogOn` method. You should re-check that fields are sent from client and those fields are put inside request body, not query string. You could check it with chrome for example, by inspecting network traffic or simply by debugging [HttpContext.Current.Request.Form property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)

Comment: I have edit my question with the Client code, do you see some problem there? it should be just a simple form post

Comment: @GibboK Ok, this exact code works fine for me, I can see all of parameters inside collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. JsonResult is an ActionResult and doesn't have anything to do with POST or GET requests.
Make sure you have wrapped your inputs with

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())

or 
<form action="" method="">
</form>
```

Not sure how you are accessing your fields.. 
Are you doing `FormCollection["form"]`? It should be `formCollection["Password"]`,  `formCollection["UserName"]` etc..